# Update a list in a Mongo document with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Im new to mongo, Im trying to add another number to the list of stgids as seen in this document:

```
{
     "hash" : "45ewqd34dewrqfer24ferferf24frec",
     "date_found" : "2020-03-17 14:34:52",
     "stgids" : [818185409533533, 818184460739521, 818181830962284]
}
```

So far I can find it and update the hash, but I don't need to update the hash, I need to add to the stgids.

```
myquery = { "hash": "45ewqd34dewrqfer24ferferf24frec" }
newvalues = { "$set": { "hash": "5ewqd34dewrqfer24ferferf24frecord" } }
mycol.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
```

if course the line newvalues = { "$set": { "hash": "5ewqd34dewrqfer24ferferf24frecord" } } is what needs to be changed to something like newvalues = { "$set": { "stigs": myquery.stigs + '1404356206' } } I just don't know what it should be.

**To be clear, I am trying update:**

```
"stgids" : [818185409533533, 818184460739521, 818181830962284]
```

**to:**

```
"stgids" : [818185409533533, 818184460739521, 818181830962284, 8181818778021642]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `push` operator, here is the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

I think this should work:

```
myquery = { "hash": "45ewqd34dewrqfer24ferferf24frec" }
newvalues = { "$push": { "stgids": "8181818778021642" } }
mycol.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
```

Comment: That is too easy. Being about 1hr into mongo, that doc link is gold. Thank you

Comment: No problem, all part of the process!